# Confused with PathView?

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to know how `PathView` works. I follow the official doc to write some sample code, the code work well but the final result is not what I wanted?

**The Code**

```js
import QtQuick

Rectangle {
    id: root
    border.color: "blue"

    Component {
        id: theDele
        Rectangle {
            id: rect
            color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(), Math.random(),Math.random(), 1)
            visible: PathView.onPath
            width: 50; height: 50
            scale: PathView.itemScale
            rotation: PathView.itemAngle
            property var rotX: PathView.itemAngle

            transform: [
                Translate {x: 25; y: 25}
            ]

            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: index + "ABC"
            }
        }
    }

    PathView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: 100
        pathItemCount: 10
        delegate: theDele

        path: Path {
            startX: 0; startY: 100

            PathAttribute {name: "itemAngle"; value: -90}
            PathAttribute {name: "itemScale"; value: 0.5}
            PathLine {x: 300; y: 100}
            PathPercent {value: 0.2}

            PathAttribute {name: "itemAngle"; value: 0}
            PathAttribute {name: "itemScale"; value: 1}
            PathLine {x: 300; y: 500}
            PathPercent {value: 0.8}

            PathAttribute {name: "itemAngle"; value: 90}
            PathAttribute {name: "itemScale"; value: 0.5}
            PathLine {x: 600; y: 500}
            PathPercent { value: 1 }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**I want work like this**
[image]

In this demo, I try to draw three `PathLine`; 1st Line proportion is
0.2;  2nd Line proportion is 0.8；3rd Line proportion is 0.2.

So 1st Line should have 2 Items; 2nd Line should have 6 Items, and 3rd Line should have 2 Items. But This demo 2nd Line has 7 Items?

And 1st Line of all Items should scale 0.5, and rotate  -90, And 2nd Line of all Items should scale 1, and rotate  0, And 3rd Line of all Items should scale 0.5, and rotate  90, But the demo items seem to scale and rotate linearly ?

Comment: Where should the missing rectangle be in the second line? Could you create an image showing what you want to get?

Comment: add a image in post.